# Table reading order in Screen Reader - JAWS, Window Eyes

Tags: html, html-table, wai-aria, screen-readers

Could anyone suggest if the reading order of a table by Screen reader like JAWS, Windows-Eye can be changed programmatically

I know the table data can be included in the same row to read it properly, but in our case, for some complex issue in values populating we have to follow this structure.

An example code is present here--> http://jsbin.com/xiloguma/2/edit

Current reading order

Name --> Amount -->  Date --> ABC --> $1200 --> 13.05.2014 --> Prepaid Customer --> Balance Due $1200 Fine $100 --> Last paid date 01.04.2014

Expected reading order

Name --> Amount -->  Date --> ABC --> Prepaid Customer--> $1200 --> Balance Due $1200 Fine $100 --> 13.05.2014 --> Last paid date 01.04.2014

Comment: try adding rowspans on first td in rows where you need two td's instead of one

Answer (score 0):

You have to use headers and id attributes to associate cells with table header cells.
[Link to H43 technique](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H43)

With Jaws you could read table header related to a cell using CTRL+ALT+ARROW.